# How to implement idempotent message handlers in the Azure ServiceBus based solutions?

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

I have a scheduler sending some 'signal' messages with same ID to the queue every minute. In same time the message handler can consume the message in time range from 5 seconds to 15 minutes in 5% of cases.

How could I implement idempotent message handling in this case so that the second message been sent from the scheduler will be ignored?

I've tried to adopt messages duplication detection but this approach doesnt work well because it uses the message occurance timestamp only (is it correct assumption?) and even in case if we have a message with same ID in the queue (maybe even locked for processing) - the new message will occur after the duplication detection time window will be closed.

I'm also thinking about sliding interval so that message handler will re-schedule the message itself after handling it. But I see there couple of other issues that makes this solution not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem an appropriate use case for Duplicate detection. Looks like you just want the process to wake up every minute and process any data it has? One option to try could be that after you are done processing you "drain the Queue" and since that will happen quickly you can then just rely on the next message to show up at most after a minute?